What determine the storage size in SharePoint online admin center
I am working on 2 online tenants, one has 1.85 TB storage size:-

the other has 1.02 storage size:-

so, what determine this size? and why each tenant has different size?

The storage size in the SharePoint Online admin center is determined by several factors:

Base Storage Allocation: Each organization gets a baseline of 1 TB of storage.
Additional Storage per License: For every licensed user, an additional 10 GB of storage is added to the total. For example, if you have 50 licensed users, you would get an extra 500 GB, making a total of 1.5 TB.
Purchased Add-ons: If your organization needs more storage, you can purchase additional storage through the Microsoft 365 Extra File Storage add-on.


thanks for the detailed reply
